# Is there any way to know when a PVC is mounted last time in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Is there any way to know when a PVC is mounted last time in k8s?

Thank you for your help

Comment: May be audit.logs could be useful, if they are enabled in your cluster. I tried at Meradata level , they aren't helpful. You may need to check at other levels.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! I wanted to delete PVCs which are not been used for a while but was not super easy.. I will check the audit log to see if I can do something with it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.